# Receiver operating characteristics curves in R - dichotomous predictors

Tags: logistic, roc

I have performed a binary logistic regression using RStudio software with whether or not a player is re-contracted or not as the dependent variable. There are 7 predictor variables with 3 of these dichotomous (0,1). It was suggested to me that generating a ROC curve based on the full model and models with single predictors only may be useful in interpreting the sensitivity of my results. My question is in relation to my dichotomous variables - is a ROC curve still useful for these variables? and am I able to use "cut off" indicators on the curve of the full model if it includes dichotomous variables?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with having dichotomous predictors in the full model, if you are looking to assess the inclusion of a single predictor, then you may want to have a look at other diagnostic checks such as explained in chapter 5 of this text: http://resource.heartonline.cn/20150528/1_3kOQSTg.pdf